# Right derived functors of composite

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I think I have proven the following.

> Let $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}$ be abelian categories such that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ have enough injectives.
> Let $F$ be an exact functor from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ which maps injectives to injectives.
> Let $G$ be a left exact functor from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{C}$.
> Then the composite $G \circ F$ is again left exact, and the right derived functors satisfy
> $$
>   \operatorname{R}^n(G \circ F)
>   \cong
>   \operatorname{R}^n(G) \circ F \,.
> $$

I’m looking for a reference (a book or an article) which confirms this result.

*Edit.* I have no experience with spectral sequences, so I’m looking for a sufficiently basic reference.

Comment: This is Tag [015M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/015M) in the Stacks Project.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is only assumed to be left exact, the composite is still left exact and the right derived functors can be computed with the Grothendieck spectral sequence. That $F$ is exact is a degenerate case, which might be treated by any author treating the general case. In any case your result follows immediately from the Grothendieck SS. I learned about it from Rotman an introduction to homological algebra.

Comment: I’ve fixed the typo regard right/left exactness, thanks for noticing it.
I sadly don’t have any experience with spectral sequences, so I’m looking for a more basic reference.

Comment: Hmm, honestly reading Rotman for the purpose of understanding the Grothendieck SS might not be totally infeasible. But it will of course take some hours and work. If you want to go deeper into these sorts of things, spectral sequences will be important to understand. Maybe also you in any case can get enough from Rotman proof of Grothendieck SS to verify your own proof? Good luck!